# Creating Custom Sized Views Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, xamarin.ios

I have created a View in Xamarin with a backing class and was wondering if I can create an instance of that class with a CGRect size. I have the following code right now:

```
using System;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace SimpleScroll.iOS
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {

        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            // UIScrollView with same width and height as ViewController
            var mainScrollView = new UIScrollView(new CGRect(0, 0, this.View.Frame.Size.Width, this.View.Frame.Size.Height));

            // Enable pagination and set other attributes
            mainScrollView.PagingEnabled = true;
            mainScrollView.ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
            mainScrollView.ShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
            mainScrollView.Bounces = false;

            int numberOfViews = 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++)
            {
                nfloat xOrigin = i * this.View.Frame.Size.Width;
                var subView = new UIView(new CGRect(xOrigin, 0, this.View.Frame.Size.Width, this.View.Frame.Size.Height));
                subView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0.5f / i, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1);
                mainScrollView.AddSubview(subView);
            }

            mainScrollView.ContentSize = new CGSize(this.View.Frame.Size.Width * numberOfViews, this.View.Frame.Size.Height);
            this.View.AddSubview(mainScrollView);
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.     
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of `var subView = new UIView(new CGRect(xOrigin, 0, this.View.Frame.Size.Width, this.View.Frame.Size.Height));`, would I be able to do the same thing with my own Menu class that I have created? How could I give Menu its own constructor so that I can do something along the lines of, `var subView = new Menu(new CGRect(...));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subclass uiview and override the frame constuctor

```
[Foundation.Register("Menu")]
public class Menu : UIView
{
  public Menu(CGRect frame) : base(frame)
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: And then inside just write: `return new Menu(new CGRect(...));`?

Comment: No not inside the new class but where you use it substitute new new UIView(...) with new Menu(...)